# Multiple sources in ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I'm working on an Android project with Android Studio. I have a layout where I need an `ImageView` to have multiple graphical sources and I want to be able to change the sources later with Java code. Can I declare multiple source files for an `ImageView` in XML?

Comment: just use imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename);

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using exactly that now and the performance is really bad. I need to change many images at one time and the app needs 3-5 seconds to do that which is to long. I thought if I give each ImageView multilpe sources in xml and then tell from java which src must be used the app would be faster.

Comment: you cant do that. The images you are selecting would be heavy. Use Universal image loader and scale down the images. Then it would be faster.